# Proving that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty } \frac{x^n}{n!}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $x$ is any real number then, $$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{x^2}{n!}=0$$

For part (b), pick any $x$ and let $N$ be an integer such that $N > |x|$. If $n > N$ we have

$$\begin{align}\Big|\frac{x^n}{n!}\Big| &= \frac{|x|}{1}\frac{|x|}{2}\frac{|x|}{3}\cdots \frac{|x|}{N-1}\frac{|x|}{N}\frac{|x|}{N+1}\cdots\frac{|x|}{n}\\&<\frac{|x|^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}\frac{|x|}{N}\frac{|x|}{N}\frac{|x|}{N}\cdots\frac{|x|}{N}\\&=\frac{|x|^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}\Bigg(\frac{|x|}{N}\Bigg)^{n-N+1} = K\Bigg(\frac{|x|}{N}\Bigg)^{n}\end{align}$$

Now I get stuck with the terms < $$\frac{\left| x\right| }{N}\frac{\left| x\right| }{N}\frac{\left| x\right| }{N}...\frac{\left| x\right| }{N}$$

First of all I do not see why we after we have expanded it in the first row why we set this less than, second row. I also do not see why we have more than one fraction with $N $ in the denominator on the second line.

I understand the objective to show that $0$ times a constant $K$ is equal to zero. But could someone take me through this step by step. I usually get induction but I'm just stuck with this one.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x$ (and the series converges absolutely for all $x\in\mathbb C$) so necessarily $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=0$. (I know this doesn't answer your question, but just something to keep in mind.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that to get the enequality "<" $$N + 1 > N \Rightarrow \frac{1}{N+1} < \frac{1}{N} \Rightarrow \frac{|x|}{N+1} < \frac{|x|}{N}\ \text{and} \ \ n > N \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N}$$

As for the second question you are taking $n > N$ so

$$1 , 2 , \ldots , N, N + 1, \ldots , n$$

**Edit:**

One more thing $$\frac{|x|}{1}\frac{|x|}{2}\frac{|x|}{3}\cdots\frac{|x|}{N-1} = \frac{|x|^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}$$

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: I would understand in row 2 if was as you described for the answer to my second question but it is multiple fractions with only N in the denominators. Why not ex. N-1, N, N+1

Comment: To each $N+1, N+2,\ldots, n$ you do as I showed on the asnwer, then you'll get each term of the multiplication, since $a<c \Rightarrow ab<cb$, if $b > 0$.

Comment: And notice that the terms $1,2, \ldots,N-2,N-1$ were already use to get $(N-1)!$

Comment: I understood the last comment as well as your edit, but I do not get why we multiply in the second line this with $\frac{\left| x\right| }{N}$*$\frac{\left| x\right| }{N}$.....,I dont see why N does not increase with 1 in each step.

Comment: Because there still terms greater than $N-1$ left to multiply, that's why comes up $\frac{|x|}{N}\frac{|x|}{N}\cdots$ Sorry if I didn't catch your last question.

Comment: Okey I guess I just have to think more and hard about it, for me it makes more sense to multiply with $\frac{\left| x\right| }{N}$*$\frac{\left| x\right| }{N+1}$*...$\frac{\left| x\right| }{n-1}$

Comment: This trick is done to get calculation easier, as long as $|\frac{x^n}{n!}|$ is bounded by something you know converges because $N > |x|$.

Comment: No worries, I am just not getting it. I would have to spend some more time trying to get it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20171/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-alexander).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to prove that,
for any positive real $x$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{x^n}{n!}
= 0
$.

Note that this is much stronger than
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{x^s}{n!}
= 0
$
for any positive real
$s$.

Let
$r_n(x)
=\frac{x^n}{n!}
$
and
$p(x)
=\frac{x^{\lceil 2x \rceil}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{\lceil 2x \rceil} j}
$.
Then,
for $n > \lceil 2x \rceil$,
$$\frac{x^n}{n!}
=\frac{x^n}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{\lceil 2x \rceil} j
\prod\limits_{j=\lceil 2x \rceil+1}^n j}
=\frac{x^{\lceil 2x \rceil}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{\lceil 2x \rceil} j}
\frac{x^{n-\lceil 2x \rceil}}{\prod\limits_{j=\lceil 2x \rceil+1}^n j}
<p(x)\frac{x^{n-\lceil 2x \rceil}}{\lceil 2x \rceil^{n-\lceil 2x \rceil}}
<p(x)\left(\frac{x}{\lceil 2x \rceil}\right)^{n-\lceil 2x \rceil}
\le \frac{p(x)}{2^{n-\lceil 2x \rceil}}
$$
or,
for $n > 0$,
$$\frac{x^{n+\lceil 2x \rceil}}{(n+\lceil 2x \rceil)!}
\le \frac{p(x)}{2^{n}}.
$$
Since
$p(x)$
is a function only of $x$,
$\frac{p(x)}{2^{n}}
\to 0
$.